# Сумма чисел с плавающей точкой. Есть мантисы и порядки

Tags: информатика

Даны 2 мантиссы 1001 и 10101 и 2 основания 0,100 и 0,101 соответственно.Все в двоичной системе. Помогите найти сумму чисел с плавающей точкой

Comment: Прочитал на [wiki](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C),  `N = M / n^p`, где `p` - это, получается, система счисления, и будет равно 2?  И в результате нам надо найти суму этих двух `N`, так? Объясните, пожалуйста мне:)

Comment: Вы же взяли задание из темы, откройте почитайте как складывать двоичные дробные числа. В столбик считайте

Comment: Подозреваю, что слева порядки, справа - мантиссы ;)